# Splashscreen in Java

Tags: java, swing, text, splash-screen

I need to figure out where in this code I need to adjust it to move the line "Splash Screen!!!" to the middle of the screen and possibly make it bigger.  I am not sure where in the code this is and it is driving me nuts.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SplashScreen extends JWindow {

private int duration;

public SplashScreen(int d) {
    duration = d;
}

// A simple little method to show a title screen in the center
// of the screen for the amount of time given in the constructor
public void showSplash() {

    JPanel content = (JPanel)getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.blue);

    // Set the window's bounds, centering the window
    int width = 700;
    int height = 450;
    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (screen.width-width)/2;
    int y = (screen.height-height)/2;
    setBounds(x,y,width,height);

    // Build the splash screen
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("java-tip.gif"));
    JLabel copyrt = new JLabel
        ("Splash Screen!!!", JLabel.CENTER);
    copyrt.setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
    content.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(copyrt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Color oraRed = new Color(200, 50, 20, 255);
    content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(oraRed, 10));

    // Display it
    setVisible(true);

    // Wait a little while, maybe while loading resources
    try { Thread.sleep(duration); } catch (Exception e) {}

    setVisible(false);
}
public void showSplashAndExit() {
    showSplash();
    System.exit(0);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Throw a nice little title page up on the screen first
    SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen(10000);

    // Normally, we'd call splash.showSplash() and get on
    // with the program. But, since this is only a test...
    splash.showSplashAndExit();
}
}
```

I am not sure why but the add code feature in this forum always makes it look weird and not indented properly.

Comment: Pee! Man you must have my posts show up with the quickness lol

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to add a swing timer.  The splash screen compiles and runs perfectly fine. What I am looking to do is completely cosmetic.

Comment: @Opjeezzeey It "appears" to run fine, but trust us, it doesn't..

Answer (score 7):

There's a few ways this might be done, but lets keep it simple.

Basically, what this does is add the `label` (background) image to the center position of the content pane.  It then applies a `BorderLayout` to `label` and adds `copyrt` to the center position of `label`...

```
public void showSplash() {

    JPanel content = (JPanel) getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.blue);

    // Set the window's bounds, centering the window
    int width = 700;
    int height = 450;
    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (screen.width - width) / 2;
    int y = (screen.height - height) / 2;
    setBounds(x, y, width, height);

    // Build the splash screen
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("java-tip.gif"));
    JLabel copyrt = new JLabel("Splash Screen!!!", JLabel.CENTER);

    content.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Fun starts here...    
//        copyrt.setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
//        content.add(copyrt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Font font = copyrt.getFont();
    copyrt.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f));
    label.add(copyrt);

    Color oraRed = new Color(200, 50, 20, 255);
    content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(oraRed, 10));

    // Display it
    setVisible(true);

    // Don't do this, as it will cause the EDT to be stopped.  Instead
    // setup some kind of callback that can tell when the resources are 
    // loaded and start the rest of the application from there...
    // Wait a little while, maybe while loading resources
    //try {
    //    Thread.sleep(duration);
    //} catch (Exception e) {
    //}

    //setVisible(false);
}
```

It's also a bad idea to do anything within the context of the EDT that may prevent it from processing further events, like using `sleep` or long running/infinite loops.

All UI interactions should executed from within the context of the EDT and all long running or potentially blocking tasks should run on a separate thread.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

**Updated**

If I try to run your example, the splash screen never appears, because `Thread.sleep` is preventing to from being show on the screen.  The fact that you "might" get it working is actually a fluke, as you are probably calling the `showSplash` method from the "main" thread and not the EDT.

Instead, if I replace `Thread.sleep` with a `SwingWorker`, I not only get the splash screen to show up, but I also get the added benefit of being able to control things like, progress updates and scheduling for disposing of the splash screen...

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SplashDemo extends JWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SplashDemo();
    }

    public SplashDemo() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                showSplash();

            }
        });
    }

    public void showSplash() {

        JPanel content = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.blue);

        // Set the window's bounds, centering the window
        int width = 700;
        int height = 450;
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (screen.width - width) / 2;
        int y = (screen.height - height) / 2;
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);

        // Build the splash screen
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/java_animated.gif")));
        JLabel copyrt = new JLabel("Splash Screen!!!", JLabel.CENTER);

        content.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        label.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        Font font = copyrt.getFont();
        copyrt.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        label.add(copyrt, gbc);

        ImageIcon wait = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/wait.gif"));
        label.add(new JLabel(wait), gbc);

        Color oraRed = new Color(200, 50, 20, 255);
        content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(oraRed, 10));

        // Display it
        setVisible(true);
        toFront();

        new ResourceLoader().execute();
    }

    public class ResourceLoader extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

            // Wait a little while, maybe while loading resources
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            setVisible(false);
        }


    }

}
```

If you like, I used the following images...

[image][image]

Comment: I really just need the splash screen. So starting the application from the end of it isn't a worry at all.

But so I just delete the comment bars to get your additions to work?

Comment: If you use `Thread.sleep` you application will "hang" as your blocking the EDT.  A better approach would be to launch the application and use something like a `SwingWorker` to do the resource loading.  Once `done` is called (on the `SwingWorker`) you can close the splash screen and open the main application window.

Answer (score 1):

You are using BorderLayout which means your container is divided into EAST, WEST NORTH, SoUTH AND CENTER. You are adding "Splash Screen" to the south. Thats why it's not centering:

```
content.add(copyrt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

You need to change the layout managers to one of the grid layouts. Alternatively, create multiple panels and add your content to them, then add to the parent container.