# Jframe loading window in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, loading

I need to do a loading window in java like this:

[image: Splash]

I tried with the jframe but I can't figure it out, I can't remove the close button, my jframe should look like a jpanel before that program begin, somebody know how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You Could...

Use Java's inbuild [splash screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) support.  This is good as it gets loaded relatively earlier in the process by the JVM itself, so it comes up reasonably quick.

The major drawback (in my opinion) is it can be troublesome to get right as it doesn't follow the standard painting process that most developers are use to and you are going to have to paint it all yourself, there's no component support

- [How do I use SplashScreen without throwing a NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964323/how-do-i-use-splashscreen-without-throwing-a-nullpointerexception/15964345#15964345)
- [How to Undo the splash screen painting in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436920/how-to-undo-the-splash-screen-painting-in-java/17437670#17437670)
- [Splash Screen Progress bar not drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802662/splash-screen-progress-bar-not-drawing/14803941#14803941)

### You Could...

Create a `JWindow`.  This is a frameless window, which won't appear on the taskbar (at least for some OSs).

You gain complete control over what and how things get displayed, as it's like dealing with any other window.

The only problem is that it won't become available for you to load until the JVM has completed loading your application.  If the JVM needs to download resources over the network, for example, this could produce an undesirable delay

For example

- [Splashscreen in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716819/splashscreen-in-java/20716873#20716873)
- [SplashScreen java change alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307684/splashscreen-java-change-alpha/19308122#19308122)
- [Why won't this draw the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915022/why-wont-this-draw-the-image/14915370#14915370)

### You Could...

Use an undecorated frame.  This is pretty much the same as the `JWindow` option, except that a taskbar icon will be displayed, but on some OSs, this can't be completely helped.

See [`Frame#setUndecorated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated(boolean)) for more details

### Final thoughts

Swing is not thread safe.  So if you're displaying a splash screen, this means you should be ensuring that whatever actions you are taking are done off the Event Dispatching Thread, possibly through the use of `SwingWorker`